# Error creating an upload session using Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to create an upload session (ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online) in order to upload a "large" document (any doc that exceeds 4MB). I am leveraging the Graph Explorer, but Graph Explorer does not provide an exact example/code snippet to do this.

I am able to use the following configuration to create my request and retrieve a successful uploadUrl in Graph Explorer

```
POST v1.0 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/{myDriveId}/items/{myItemId}:/test.pdf:/createUploadSession
```

In my application I am able to call CreateUploadSession successfully, but the uploadUrl return is null.

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.CreateUploadSession.CreateUploadSessionPostRequestBody
{
};

var res = await graphClient.Drives["{myDriveId}"].Items["{myItemId}/:/testFile.pdf"].CreateUploadSession.PostAsync(requestBody);

var uploadUrl = res.UploadUrl;
```

My application is using Microsoft.Graph 5.11

Would this be the correct method when creating my upload session?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dug further into the Items object, I found Items[].ItemsWithPath()

after changing my statement to

```
var res = await graphClient.Drives["{myDriveId}"].Items["{myItemId}"].ItemWithPath("testFile.pdf").CreateUploadSession.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

my request is returning a new UploadUrl